# Cross-compile of Qt for Raspberry Pi fails for XCB support with updated toolchain

Tags: cross-compilation, qt

I had successfully cross-compiled Qt 5.11.2 for Raspbian Buster on Ubuntu 18.04 host mostly using these guides:

https://www.ics.com/blog/configuring-qt-creator-raspberry-pi

https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS

(I had to tweak a couple of things, using the /gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf compiler and replacing ~/ with /home/{username} etc.)

But I ended up with a working Qt distro on the Pi and could cross-compile and debug remotely, runnning an example app with -platform xcb to use X11.

I then discovered that the official Raspberry Pi toolchain is woefully out of date (GCC 4.8.3) and my real-world app needs more up-to-date C++ features.

So I found a more recent GCC toolchain here: https://github.com/Pro/raspi-toolchain

I rebuilt Qt from scratch using the same sysroot as before and exactly the same configure options.

However, the resulting build Of Qt now does not include XCB support. If I delve into qt-everywhere-src-5.11.2/config.tests/xcb and make, compilation fails with this:

```
/opt/cross-pi-gcc/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -c -march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a53 -mfpu=crypto-neon-fp-armv8 -mfloat-abi=hard --sysroot=/home/nick/raspi/sysroot --sysroot=/home/nick/raspi/sysroot -O2 -w -fPIC  -I. -I/media/nick/CrossCompile/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.2/qtbase/mkspecs/devices/linux-rasp-pi3-g++ -o main.o main.cpp
main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: xcb/xcb.h: No such file or directory
 #include <xcb/xcb.h>
```

But with the previous toolchain (same sysroot & Qt sources) it succeeds:

```
/home/nick/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -c -march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a53 -mfpu=crypto-neon-fp-armv8 -mfloat-abi=hard --sysroot=/home/nick/raspi/sysroot --sysroot=/home/nick/raspi/sysroot -O2 -std=gnu++11 -w -fPIC  -I. -I/media/nick/CrossCompile/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.2/qtbase/mkspecs/devices/linux-rasp-pi3-g++ -o main.o main.cpp
/home/nick/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -mfloat-abi=hard --sysroot=/home/nick/raspi/sysroot --sysroot=/home/nick/raspi/sysroot -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/nick/raspi/sysroot/opt/vc/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/nick/raspi/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/nick/raspi/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -o xcb main.o   -lxcb
```

I don't understand why the newer compiler can't find the xcb.header from sysroot while the older compiler can.

Here's the g++ -v output of both compilers:

```
nick@ubuntu:~/raspi$ tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/media/nick/CrossCompile/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-linux-gnueabihf
Configured with: /home/zhehe01/work/bzr/pi-build/builds/arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-linux/.build/src/gcc-linaro-4.8-2014.03/configure --build=x86_64-build_unknown-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-build_unknown-linux-gnu --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf --prefix=/home/zhehe01/work/bzr/pi-build/builds/arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-linux/install --with-sysroot=/home/zhehe01/work/bzr/pi-build/builds/arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-linux/install/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --disable-multilib --enable-multiarch --with-arch=armv6 --with-tune=arm1176jz-s --with-fpu=vfp --with-float=hard --with-pkgversion='crosstool-NG linaro-1.13.1+bzr2650 - Linaro GCC 2014.03' --with-bugurl=https://bugs.launchpad.net/gcc-linaro --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-libmudflap --enable-libgomp --enable-libssp --with-gmp=/home/zhehe01/work/bzr/pi-build/builds/arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-linux/.build/arm-linux-gnueabihf/build/static --with-mpfr=/home/zhehe01/work/bzr/pi-build/builds/arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-linux/.build/arm-linux-gnueabihf/build/static --with-mpc=/home/zhehe01/work/bzr/pi-build/builds/arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-linux/.build/arm-linux-gnueabihf/build/static --with-isl=/home/zhehe01/work/bzr/pi-build/builds/arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-linux/.build/arm-linux-gnueabihf/build/static --with-cloog=/home/zhehe01/work/bzr/pi-build/builds/arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-linux/.build/arm-linux-gnueabihf/build/static --with-libelf=/home/zhehe01/work/bzr/pi-build/builds/arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-linux/.build/arm-linux-gnueabihf/build/static --enable-threads=posix --disable-libstdcxx-pch --enable-linker-build-id --enable-plugin --enable-gold --with-local-prefix=/home/zhehe01/work/bzr/pi-build/builds/arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-linux/install/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc --enable-c99 --enable-long-long --with-float=hard
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.3 20140303 (prerelease) (crosstool-NG linaro-1.13.1+bzr2650 - Linaro GCC 2014.03)
```

and

```
nick@ubuntu:~/raspi$ /opt/cross-pi-gcc/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/opt/cross-pi-gcc/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/cross-pi-gcc/libexec/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8.3.0/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-linux-gnueabihf
Configured with: ../gcc-8.3.0/configure --prefix=/opt/cross-pi-gcc --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --with-arch=armv6 --with-fpu=vfp --with-float=hard --disable-multilib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.3.0 (GCC)
```

What could cause the later compiler to not find the xcb headers?

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly specify the path to `xcb.h`?

Comment: No I haven't, but the only change is the toolchain. The sysroot and Qt sources are the same and xcb/xcb.h exists in the expected location. Everything else compiles successfully. I've sinced switched to Windows hosted cross-compilation and have moved on, but still confused why this would happen.

Comment: Well, if you're not interested in investigating this, I guess nobody else is either.

Comment: @Dmitry - Thanks. My question is why would a different toolchain not pick up XCB whereas the first toolchain did. If I was to 'fix' the problem by explicitly specifying the path then I'd still be none the wiser as to the difference between the toolchains.

Comment: I didn't suggest this as a fix, but as a test to confirm that it's indeed a path problem. Anyway, I'm glad you have figured that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can examine the default search paths by issuing this command to gcc:

```
gcc -xc -E -v -
```

So comparing the output that gcc command under the two toolchains I can see that the newer one is lacking some default include directories.

Older toolchain:

```
...
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /media/nick/CrossCompile/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/include
 /media/nick/CrossCompile/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/include-fixed
 /media/nick/CrossCompile/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include
 /home/nick/raspi/sysroot/usr/include/.
 /home/nick/raspi/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf
End of search list.
```

Later toolchain:

```
...
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /opt/cross-pi-gcc/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8.3.0/include
 /opt/cross-pi-gcc/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8.3.0/include-fixed
 /opt/cross-pi-gcc/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8.3.0/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include
End of search list.
```

So the later toolchain is not picking up /usr/include which is where xcb/xcb.h lives.

Comment: I’m new to qt and cross compiling, and I believe I’m running into this same problem (was following a similar guide to the one you linked). How did you get the toolchain/gcc to search the missing paths?